# How to read multiples set of results from json?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using the following code to get a JSON results with employees information but sometimes could get more than one set of results and I need to read them all.

```
function get_employee(employee_id) {
    var getJSON = function(url) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var status = xhr.status;
          if (status == 200) {
            resolve(xhr.response);
          } else {
            reject(status);
          }
        };
        xhr.send();
      });


    };

    getJSON('https://company.com/index.php?employee_id=' + employee_id + '&format=json').then(function(data) {
        $('#employee').val('');
        if (data.employees.length > 0) {

            var employee = data.employees.shift();
            document.getElementById("date_1").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_1;
            document.getElementById("date_2").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_2;
            document.getElementById("date_3").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_3;

        } else {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    }, function(status) { //error detection....
      alert('Someting went wrong.');
    });
}
```

Sometimes I could get a result like this:

```
{ 
   "employees":[ 
      { 
         "employee":{ 
            "EMPLOYEE_ID":"125678",
            "DATE_1":"30-06-2018",
            "DATE_2":"30-06-2017",
            "DATE_3":"12-07-2021"
         }
      },
      { 
         "employee":{ 
            "EMPLOYEE_ID":"125678",
            "DATE_1":"01-04-2021",
            "DATE_2":"01-04-2021",
            "DATE_3":"02-04-2022"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And I need to store all the dates involved. How can I get the second set of results?

Comment: You have to loop over `data.employees`.

Comment: `data.employees[1].employee.DATE_1` and so on

Comment: Or `data.employees.forEach(...)`

Comment: You'll also need a table in the HTML, not just 3 specific IDs to fill in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic stuff on js objects:

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#my-table')
  ,   data = { employees: 
        [ { employee: { EMPLOYEE_ID: "125678", DATE_1: "30-06-2018", DATE_2: "30-06-2017", DATE_3: "12-07-2021"} } 
        , { employee: { EMPLOYEE_ID: "125678", DATE_1: "01-04-2021", DATE_2: "01-04-2021", DATE_3: "02-04-2022"} } 
        ] }
  ;
for ( let elm of data.employees )
  {
  let nRow = myTable.insertRow(-1)
    , col  = 0
    ;
  nRow.insertCell(col++).textContent = elm.employee.DATE_1
  nRow.insertCell(col++).textContent = elm.employee.DATE_2
  nRow.insertCell(col++).textContent = elm.employee.DATE_3
  };
let Rowhead = myTable.createTHead().insertRow(-1);
['DATE_1','DATE_2','DATE_3'].forEach((T,i)=>Rowhead.insertCell(i).textContent = T);
```

```css
Table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: .7em; }
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 2px 10px; }
thead { background-color: turquoise;}
```

```html
<table id="my-table"></table>
```

Comment: how can I use this code on my code? How can I put my json inside "data = { }"

Comment: @Rodrick https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (data.employees.length > 0) {

    var employee = data.employees.shift();
    document.getElementById("date_1").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_1;
    document.getElementById("date_2").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_2;
    document.getElementById("date_3").textContent = employee.employees.DATE_3;

}
```

to

```
var doc = document, I, all = data.employees;
I = function(id){ // I put this here to teach you something - less writing code
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
if(all.length){
  var date1 = I('date_1'), date2 = I('date_2'), date3 = I('date_3'), person, id; // let's not get those elements in a loop, if they're not dynamic
  all.forEach(function(o){
    person = o.employee; id = person.EMPLOYEE_ID; date1.textContent = person.DATE_1; 
    date2.textContent = person.DATE_2; date3.textContent = person.DATE_3;
  });
}
```

If there wasn't an else condition after that if then you could just run the loop without testing for the length, by the way.